# Selecting lines of a file specified by a list of strings

Tags: python, string, list, file

I have a python list of some strings. I also have a text file (say X) where each line has a word token and some floats after that each separated by a space. # of floats in every line is constant.

My objective is to take only the lines corresponding to the strings in the list and save it as a text file. And if any string in the list is absent in the file X then its corresponding floats should be random and between -1 and 1.

Toy example:

```
list = ['the','in','red']
```

File X:

```
in 0.5 -0.1 -0.6             
good 0.2 0.4 -0.3            
on 0.4 0.6 0.6  
the 0.01 -0.05 0.5
```

What I want in a new text file:

```
the 0.01 -0.05 0.5  
in 0.5 -0.1 -0.6  
red -0.2 0.3 0.7
```

The list has around 400000 strings and the text file has around 3 Million lines.
Please suggest an effective way to do this. Any advice would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use grep if you want to find in one file.

```
### let's create a file find_strings.py

import os

list = ['the','in','red']
for l in list :
   os.system('grep ' + str(l) + ' fileX.txt')

### after saving the file, run the below command in the console . 
### $ python find_strings.py > list_found_strings.txt
```